# Quad Partition Matrix Search

Tags: java, search, matrix, netbeans

The program I have is supposed to divide the matrix into four quadrants continuously until it finds the given value.  With the current program it runs forever.  How do I get it to post the number I search for?

```
 public static void DivideAndConquerSearch(int target, int fromRow, int toRow, int fromCol, int toCol, int[][] matrix, int comparison_counter) {
    boolean found = false;

    while (!found) {

        int i = fromRow + (toRow - fromRow) / 2;
        int j = fromCol + (toCol - fromCol) / 2;

        if (matrix[i][j] == target) {
            found = true;
        } else if (matrix[i][j] < target) {
            if (i + 1 <= toRow) {
                found = false;
                DivideAndConquerSearch(target, i + 1, toRow, fromCol, toCol, matrix, comparison_counter);
            } else if (j - 1 >= fromCol) {
                found = false;
                DivideAndConquerSearch(target, fromRow, toRow, fromCol, j - 1, matrix, comparison_counter);
            }
        }
        comparison_counter++;
    }
    if (found == true) {
        System.out.println(target + " found in " + comparison_counter + " comparisons using recursive search");
    } else {
        System.out.println(target + " NOT found in " + comparison_counter + " comparisons using recursive search");
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the assertion valid for the elements of int[][] matrix?

Comment: I don't know what algorithm you are trying to use here, but increasing the lower bound of rows and decreasing the upper bound of colums will just reduce the search space to the lower right hand corner of the matrix. And if the value you are searching for isn't met on this progression, you are stuck. There's no condition to terminate the search in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up something that simply searches all over the array (brute-force kinds) using a recursive approach. It splits the 2D array into 4 quadrants and search NW, NE, SW, SE. I used an `OR` condition to check if it is found in any of the quadrants. So, if number is found in NW, it won't search the rest (yay!). Let me know if you have any questions. The code isn't the prettiest or the most optimized, and I have kinda chosen to leave it that way so that you can understand what I am doing a little better. The full class, including a (**very** basic) test...

```
public class Divide_Conquer_2dArr {

    private static boolean divideAndConquer(int[][] arr, int target) {

        /* IDEA */
        // NORTH_WEST [Kanye West joke(?)]
        // need to search row-wise from [0,row-1], col-wise from [0, col-1]

        // NORTH_EAST
        // need to search row-wise from [0,row-1], col-wise from [col, maxCol]

        // SOUTH_WEST
        // need to search row-wise from [row, maxRow], col-wise from [0, col-1]

        // SOUTH_EAST
        // need to search row-wise from [row, maxRow], col-wise from [col, maxCol]

        return divideAndConquerHelper(arr, target, 0, arr[0].length-1, 0, arr.length-1);
    }

    private static boolean divideAndConquerHelper(int[][] arr, int target, int minCol, 
            int maxCol, int minRow, int maxRow) {
        // print relevant stuff
        printArr(arr,  minCol, maxCol, minRow, maxRow);

        if(minCol == maxCol || minRow == maxRow) {

            if(minCol == maxCol) {
                for(int i = minRow ; i <= maxRow ; i++)
                    if(arr[i][minCol] == target) {
                        System.out.println("Found!");
                        return true;
                    }
            }

            else if(minRow == maxRow) {
                for(int i = minCol ; i <= maxCol ; i++)
                    if(arr[minRow][i] == target) {
                        System.out.println("Found!");
                        return true;
                    }
            }

            return false;
        }

        int midRow = (maxRow + minRow)/2;
        int midCol = (maxCol + minCol)/2;


        return 
                // north-west quadrant
                divideAndConquerHelper(arr, target, minCol, midCol, minRow, midRow)
                ||
                // north-east quadrant
                divideAndConquerHelper(arr, target, midCol+1, maxCol, minRow, midRow)
                ||
                // south-west quadrant
                divideAndConquerHelper(arr, target, minCol, midCol, midRow+1, maxRow)
                ||
                // south-east quadrant
                divideAndConquerHelper(arr, target, midCol+1, maxCol, midRow+1, maxRow);
    }

    // prints arr[minRow..maxRow][minCol..maxCol] inclusive
    private static void printArr(int[][] arr, int minCol, 
            int maxCol, int minRow, int maxRow) {
        for(int i = minRow ; i <= maxRow ; i++ ) {
            for(int j = minCol ; j <= maxCol ; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("==================================");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[][]
                {
                    {1,2,3,4},
                    {6,7,8,9},
                    {11,12,13,14},
                    {16,17,18,19},
                    {21,22,23,24}
                };

        boolean retVal = divideAndConquer(arr, 12);
        if(!retVal)
            System.out.println("Not found :(");
    }
}
```